# How thread-safe is V4L2?

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety, posix, v4l2

I couldn't find any mention of the thread safety characteristics of V4L2, except for [this e-mail from 2008](http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/linux-uvc-devel/2008-June/003665.html). It talks about the big kernel lock, which I guess is gone now, right?

Does anybody have any updated information on this? Can I `ioctl` (I'm thinking especially about `VIDIOC_DQBUF` and `VIDIOC_QBUF`) the same V4L2 file descriptor from multiple threads without serialization? The discussion cited above does seem to indicate that the answer is driver-dependent, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification does not mention whether V4L2 is thread-safe. However it seems that some implementations actually are thread safe.

POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 require that all functions specified in the standard shall be thread-safe, except some specific functions. ioctl() is not one of them, so it IS thread-safe.
However, ioctl() is a cancellation point, so the thread can be terminated once it reaches ioctl().

I think that the correct solution is to assume that V4L2 is not thread-safe and do the locking accordingly.